# On finding a limit by dividing by the highest exponent

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Sometimes it’s easy to divide by the highest exponent to find a limit.

$${{{n^3} + 4{n^2}} \over {\root 3 \of n  + \root 4 \of {{n^3}} }}$$

So, in the above example (which I just made up; there’s nothing special about it), you should divide by $n^3$. How do you handle the denominator which involves roots?

Comment: Root is a fraction exponent.

Comment: P.S: limit to when? 0 or $\infty$?

Comment: limit to infinity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same method for fraction exponent:

$${{{n^3} + 4{n^2}} \over {\root 3 \of n  + \root 4 \of {{n^3}} }}\sim_\infty\frac{n^3}{n^{3/4}}\ \text{since} \ n^{1/3}=_\infty o(n^{3/4})$$

Answer (score 2):

Explanation of Exponential Division.

The cube root of $n$ can be written as $$n^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

So it'd be $$\frac{n^{\frac{1}{3}}}{n^3}$$ which is simply $$n^{(\frac{1}{3} - 3)} = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}} = n^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: But the other term in the denominator dominates.

Comment: @RossMillikan Isnt the other term $n^{\frac{3}{4}}$?

Comment: Yes, it is, which is greater than $n^{\frac 13}$ for large $n$

Comment: @RossMillikan, okay, I see your point. Yes is it greater than $n^{\frac{1}{3}}$, but I was dividing by the highest exponent in the entire expression which would be $n^3$

Comment: I see that and agree that you are correct, but for limits to $\infty$ (which OP didn't specify but implied) it is more useful to consider the other term.  It turns out the thing goes to $\infty$ still.

Comment: $$n^{(\frac{1}{3} - 3)} =  n^{-\frac{8}{3}}$$ **not** $n^{-\frac{2}{3}}$