# Dividing By The Denominator's Leading Term

Tags: calculus

In a given polynomial a way to simplify an expression to find the limit is to the divide both numerator and denominator by the denominator's leading term.

Why we divide by the denominator's leading term and not the numerator? is there a counter example that would not work?

For example in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580996/on-finding-a-limit-by-dividing-by-the-highest-exponent) we can dvide both in $n^3$ or $n^{4\over 3}$

Answer (score 1):

You divide the numerator and denominator by $x^n$ where $n$ is the maximum among the degrees of polynomial in the numerator and denominator. Yes and $n$ can be a fraction too. Just take the highest power of $x$ that occurs in the quadratic polynomial.

Comment: It does not matter where the biggest $x^n$ is located? numerator or denominator?

Comment: No it does not matter. That is to ensure that as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the terms $\frac{a_ix^i}{x^n}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Miz Of course the particular term where $i=n$ just approaches $a_i,$ not zero.